# Solution to re-use child class method within its siblings (ASP.NET/VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, design-patterns, webforms, mvp

I have 5 web forms which contains same user controls with different functionality. The current system follows MVP pattern. All these web forms inherited from a single base class (Please refer the following image.). Now, I have to disable each and every form individually for a certain condition which is common for all the forms. So, I wrote a method for one of the forms to disable each and every field in its user controls and it works fine. I can re-use this method for the rest of the web forms as they all contain the same set of user controls.
[image]

The DisableControls() method calls DisableInputs() method of each user control:

[image]

This would be duplicated in other web form classes. Does anyone can suggest a suitable solution to re-use this method?

Comment: Put it in the base class that all the forms derive from..?

Comment: Thanks.. I have edited my post to explain the code.
If I put DisableControls() in BaseClass then, I have to pass user controls as parameters. Otherwise, I cannot access the user controls in child class from base class. So, it would be similar to putting DisableControls() method in a common utility class as a shared method. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

Comment: Sounds about right, yes. If, however, you have 5 forms which all have `UserControl1` and `UserControl2` then you have the option to put them too in the base class. And then your method has access to them. Anyway,  don't over engineer this unless there will be even more forms with the same structure...

Comment: Yes, this is an existing system that I have to customize. I was curious whether there is a specific solution to handle this type of situation. I agree with you about over engineering :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you include an empty sub in your base class for `DisableControls()` you can override this in the child classes without having to give the base class specific knowledge of the child classes.

Something like this:

```
Public Class Base
    Overridable Sub DisableControls()
        'Do nothing if nothing is implemented
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Instance1
    Inherits Base
    Public Overrides Sub DisableControls()
        Me.UserControl1.DisableInputs()
        Me.UserControl2.DisableInputs()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Instance2
    Inherits Base
    Public Overrides Sub DisableControls()
        Me.UserControl3.DisableInputs()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done a similar thing to make the code reusable.